# После получения json пропадает рандомная его часть

Tags: python, json, сокет, websocket

Имеется написанный на python с использованием библиотеки socket модуль который принимает с гитлаб Json, чтобы потом его распарсить в след модуле

При передаче json иногда пропадает рандомная его часть, никак не могу понять в чем загвоздка
код парсера

```
#time
seconds = time.time()
local_time = time.ctime(seconds)

#HDRS
HDRS = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'
HDRS_404 = 'HTTP/1.1 404 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n'

# create webserver socket
socket_server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket_server.bind(('ip', 8888))
socket_server.listen(356)
socket_server.settimeout(5)

#Start procesing incoming json
def start_my_server():
    #def of compare secret key
    def load_secret(secret_token, data):
        try:
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'I LOAD JSON')
            print('load_secret')
            key = str(data)
            key = re.findall(f'X-Gitlab-Token:...............', key)
            print(key)
            key = str(key).replace("['X-Gitlab-Token: ", '')
            key = str(key).replace("']", '')
            print(key)
            print(secret_token, ' !!! ', key)
            if secret_token == key:
                socket_server.settimeout(None)
                try_to_verification(key)
            else:
                fail_verifivcation()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.load_secret {e}')

    def try_to_verification(key):
        try:
            print(key, 'key try_to_verification')
            client_socket.send(HDRS.encode('utf-8'))
            client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
            # with open(f"path to file('{local_time}').json", 'w+') as output_file:
            #     json.dump(data, output_file)
            with open(f"path to file", 'w+') as file:
                json.dump(data, file)
                file.close()
            print('next step')
            json_dump_for_proj(data)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.try_to_verification {e}')

    def fail_verifivcation():
        try:
            print('Not find')
            client_socket.send(HDRS_404.encode('utf-8'))
            client_socket.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
            addresses = open('ipPOST', 'a')
            addresses.write(str(address) + f'{local_time}\n')
            addresses.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.fail_verifivcation {e}')

    while True:
        print('start loop')
        try:
            print('try loop')
            while True:
                print('Working...')
                client_socket, address = socket_server.accept()
                print('loop', address)
                data = client_socket.recv(1048576).decode('utf-8')
                # slack_message_pipe(step=f'I GOT JSON')
                load_secret(secret_token, data)
        except Exception as e:
            # slack_message_pipe(step=f'start_my_server.socket.error {e}')
            print(f'pass try {e}')
            fail_verifivcation()
```

код распарсивателя

```
home_path = os.environ['home']

# time
seconds = time.time()
local_time = time.ctime(seconds)


def json_dump_for_proj(data):
    os.chdir(home_path)
    try:
        data = str(data).replace('null', '0')
        # Find head json
        data = re.sub('POST / HTTP/1.1\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        # data = re.sub(',total_commits_count.*', '}', data)
        data = re.sub('POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        # data = re.sub('.total_commits_count.*', '}', data)
        data = re.sub('POST.*\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = re.sub('"POST / HTTP/1.1\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = re.sub('"POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = re.sub('"POST.*\r\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n.*\n', '', data)
        data = json.loads(data)
        # parse needly info
        # Branch
        # print(data['ref'])
        branch = data['ref']
        # print(data['commits'])
        for keys in data['commits']:
            # id
            id_hash = keys['id']
            # author
            # name
            name = keys['author']['name']
            # email
            email = keys['author']['email']
            # files
            # added
            added = keys['added']
            for _ in range(len(added) + 1):
                for j in added:
                    if 'path to file' not in j:
                        added.remove(j)
            # print('path to file' not in added[-1])
            # modif
            modified = keys['modified']
            for _ in range(len(modified) + 1):
                for k in modified:
                    if 'force-app/main/default' not in k:
                        print(k)
                        modified.remove(k)
            print(id_hash, name, email, branch, modified, sep='\n' + '*' * 100 + '\n')
            list_of = [(name, email), added, modified, id_hash]
            # write_list(list_of)
        # print(not modified and not added)
        message_dict = {"name": name, "email": email, "modified": modified, "added": added}
        if not modified and not added:
            slack_message_pipe_good(
                step=f' \nI got commit by {message_dict.get("name")}\nEmail: {message_dict.get("email")}\n\nBut it is empty, pass')
            return
        try:
            # slack_message_pipe_good(step=f' \nI got commit by {message_dict.get("name")}\nEmail: {message_dict.get("email")}\n\nInside this commit, the following changes\nadded:{message_dict.get("added")}\nmodified:{message_dict.get("modified")}\n\n I am going to the next step')
            git_checkout(id_hash, message_dict)
        except Exception as e:
            slack_message_pipe(step=f'ERROS ON STEP before_deploy_Parse_Json.json_dump_for_proj: {e}')
            return
    except Exception as e:
        with open(f'data_failure{local_time}.json',
                  'w+') as data_failure:
            data_failure.write(data)
            data_failure.close()
            slack_message_pipe(step=f' before_deploy_Parse_Json.json_dump_for_proj {e}')


def write_list(list_of):
    try:
        with open(f'path to file', 'w+') as output_file:
            output_file.write(str(list_of) + '\n')
            output_file.close()
            print('I all write')
    except Exception as e:
        slack_message_pipe(step=f' before_deploy_Parse_Json.write_list {e}')


# with open('data.json', 'r') as json_file:
#     data = json.load(json_file)
#     json_dump_for_proj(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Parse_Json')
```

UPD:
пример json

```
POST / HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nUser-Agent: GitLab/15.1.0-pre\r\nX-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook\r\nX-Gitlab-Token: \"X-Gitlab-Token\"\r\nX-Gitlab-Event-Uuid: X-Gitlab-Event-Uuid\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: nHost:8888\r\nContent-Length: 2736\r\n\r\n{\"object_kind\":\"push\",\"event_name\":\"push\",\"before\":\"event_name\",\"after\":\"event_name\",\"ref\":\"refs/heads/Staging\",\"checkout_sha\":\"checkout_sha\",\"message\":null,\"user_id\":user_id,\"user_name\":\"user_name \",\"user_username\":\"user_name.Sapozhnikov\",\"user_email\":\"\",\"user_avatar\":\"url\",\"project_id\":project_id,\"project\":{\"id\":project_id,\"name\":\"name\",\"description\":\"name repository.\",\"web_url\":\"url\",\"avatar_url\":null,\"git_ssh_url\":\"url\",\"git_http_url\":\"url",\"namespace\":\"Salesforce-Gold\",\"visibility_level\":0,\"path_with_namespace\":\"url\",\"default_branch\":\"master\",\"ci_config_path\":null,\"homepage\":\"url\",\"url\":\"url\",\"ssh_url\":\"url\",\"http_url\":\"url\"},\"commits\":[{\"id\":\"\",\"message\":\"message steps\",\"timestamp\":\"2timestamp\",\"url\":\"url\",\"author\":{\"name\":\"user_name\",\"email\":\"user_name.user_name@user_name.com\"},\"added\":[\"__Release_Notes/Q2.5/CE-2823.docx\",\"__Release_Notes/Q2.5/CE-2823_PROD.csv\",\"__Release_Notes/Q2.5/CE-2823_UAT.csv\"],\"modified\":[\"__Release_Notes/Q2.5.md\"],\"removed\":[]}],\"total_commits_count\":1,\"push_options\":{},\"repository\":{\"name\":\"NA_GOLD\",\"url\":\"url\",\"description\":\"North America Gold Org repository.\",\"homepage\":\"url\",\"git_http_url\":\"url\",\"git_ssh_url\":\"url\",\"visibility_level\":0}}
```

Comment: Ну добавьте всё же пример: посылался такой-то `json`, дошёл такой-то. Примеры всегда нужны для диагностики ошибок.

Comment: @CrazyElf json присылает gitlab, от его примера мало что измениться

Comment: Похоже, вы не хотите, чтобы вам помогали. Что ж, дело ваше. )

Comment: @CrazyElf Дело же не в json, а в коде, если бы была проблема в json я бы обратился в gitlab с поддержкой
Пример json ничего не даст

Comment: @CrazyElf пример json добавил